# What is the word that means ready to step into battle whenever necessary?

Tags: word-request

What is the word that means ready to step into battle whenever necessary? It's used to describe someone often in the military on standby basically.

Comment: The media's favourite word is **poised** to do whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to a "[military reserve force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_reserve_force)", or often spoken as "military reserves". Those are the people who are trained as military, but only get called up for active duty if there is a need.

If there are military forces being added to an existing military operation -- either an ongoing battle, operation, occupation, etc., those are "reinforcements".